# Adding a dynamic legend based off of KML file contents within Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth

I'm looking to create a dynamic legend within google earth that's generated based off of the KML file (sample file used in example below can be found [here](https://www.spc.noaa.gov/products/outlook/archive/2019/day1otlk_20190312_1300.kmz)).

For example, if there is an "enhanced", "slight", "marginal", and "general", a legend would be created with those values with the associated color (thus, 4 values). Likewise, if there was only "marginal" and "general", then a legend would be created with those two values.

My question here is, is there a way to generate it in Google Earth as a "one-click" (or "two-click") solution? I.e. I load the KML/KMZ file and I click a button to create a legend that bases itself off of the values of the KML file. I'm thinking that there isn't and I'd have to write a script to get me to this "one click" solution.

Answer (score 1):

Google Earth Pro (the classic desktop app) can create legends from your KML, but maybe not in the way you want.  It's part of the "Save Image" tool, accessible from the File menu > Save > Save Image, or from the "Save Image" button on the toolbar (2nd from the right).  When you go to save an image, it gives you options for a title box, legend box, scale, compass and HTML box. The "Map Options" button that appears below the tool bar lets you turn those things on or off, and lets you select the desired image resolution before saving your map view to a JPG image.

If you have a KML on the map when you go to save an image, you'll see that the Legend is auto-generated from the features in your KML (see image below). If you click on the Legend box, you can select which items to include or not... or to refresh the auto-generated legend from your current view.

It works pretty well. The caveat is that the only useful thing you can do with it is export it as part of a larger image.  There's no easy way to get that legend, and then somehow add it to your KML for viewing with the map.  So if this is for generating a map image with legend, then you're good to go... otherwise you can export the image, crop out everything but the legend, and then use that legend image in a balloon in your KML or elsewhere.

[image: Google Earth KML Legend]